# UITableViewCell constraints scrolling bug with UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and using [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to setup constraints depends on my cell style (enum). For example I have a right wrapper with some buttons and sometimes I want to use excluded path for my `UITextView` when width of my wrapper isn't equal zero. All works good only after I scroll down to this cell and scroll up and down again. On the first try I have [image]

And after I scroll up and down I have

[image]

```
- (void)setCellType:(ReservationCellType)cellType
{
    self->_cellType = cellType;
    CGFloat rightButtonsWrapperWidth = 0;
    CGFloat rightButtonsWrapperHeight = 0;
    if (cellType == ReservationCellTypeSeating) {
        if (self.reservationStatus == ReservationStatusArrived) {
            rightButtonsWrapperWidth = 100.f;
            rightButtonsWrapperHeight = 100.f;
        } else {
            rightButtonsWrapperWidth = 0;
            rightButtonsWrapperHeight = 0;
        }
    }

    [self.rightButtonsWrapper mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(rightButtonsWrapperWidth);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(rightButtonsWrapperHeight);
    }];

    if (cellType == ReservationCellTypeSeating) {
        if (self.reservationStatus == ReservationStatusArrived) {
            [self addRightButtonsWrapperExcludedPathWidth:rightButtonsWrapperWidth height:rightButtonsWrapperHeight];
        }
    }

}
```

The code of `addRightButtonsWrapperExcludedPathWidth:height:`

```
- (void)addRightButtonsWrapperExcludedPathWidth:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.rightButtonsWrapper.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.rightButtonsWrapper.frame), width, height);
    CGRect rightWrapperExclusionRect = [self.noteTextView convertRect:frame fromView:self.wrapper];
    UIBezierPath *rightWrapperExcludedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rightWrapperExclusionRect];
    self.noteTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[rightWrapperExcludedPath];
    [self.wrapper layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I call `[cell layoutIfNeeded]`; Help me out, please. And the second question is - my calculations always wrong before I call reloadData. And after some scrolling I got a lot of layout problems. Please, help me.

Comment: Try setup your constraints in the `- (void)layoutSubviews` method of your custom cell, I hope this helps

Comment: @ReinierMelian this doesn't help :(